# Perfectly aligned images on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Is there a JS plugin that can achieve a similar effect to this:

https://pressfocus.pl/photos?query=16.04.2017%20Augsburg%20Koeln

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of plugins. you should google it first

Try this

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: Thank you for the google tip kind sir. Some times your head gets clouded you can't even think straight.